# How can I change the portnumber (example.com:1234) to something like (example.com)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a web application on Ubuntu, and serve it with http-server. Because there are more instances of this application running (with some differences between the instances), most of them have a portnumber behind them. However, I would like to have one root web application which now runs on example.com:1234 to be accesible on example.com

Are there any other ways to make this possible?

I have tried using the --proxy flag of http-server, but I can't seem to make the URL work. There is another package called http-proxy, but this would take some time to make it work (extra code). I hope there is a simpler solution than installing another node package.

Comment: Please go through ngnix setup, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04. this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think you could change the port number, but if you want to change the host name you could just do the following,

/etc/hosts (or it's equivalents on other OS's) is used to resolve hostnames to some ip without asking to dns servers.

You can use in your `/etc/hosts:`

```
127.0.0.1 myserver.com
```

And then open http://myserver.com:3333 in your browser and it will connect to 127.0.0.1 to 3333 port.

I am talking about things locally. Otherwise host your server and bind it using ngnix.conf or IP tables.

Answer (score 0):

If root web application is already running, if it facilitates changing port number you can change that to port number example.com:80, so that it will automatically picked up when you hit the URL with example.com.